# Making a pop up modal using dynamically created buttons / divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-sheets

I'm currently building a sort of image selection and would like to make it so when clicking the magnifying glass icon on the images it pops up a modal showing the whole picture, title and description. I have one problem though, all of my info is being pulled in from Google Sheets using Sheetrock.js and has a template with Handlebars.js.

```
// Define spreadsheet URL.
var mySpreadsheet = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1it6QkBRPDsIqYOtr_UbFFmHBEADVkKaKjdghLSX5d3E/edit#gid=0';

// Compile Handlebars template for team RBI leaders.
var RBITemplate = Handlebars.compile($('#team-rbi-template').html());

// Load top five team RBI leaders.
$('#image-grid').sheetrock({
  url: mySpreadsheet,
  rowHandler: RBITemplate
});
```

I've had my concept sort of working, except when I call `{{cells.ImageURL}}` it likes to only show the first image(cell) in the pop up. Which doesn't make sense since it just shows all the queries on the load up of the page in the `#image-grid` container. I want the modal to have an x button in the top right, as well as, clicking on the fullscreen modal will close it.

Here is what I have built to make the modal:

HTML

```
<div class="modal">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <div class="modal__contents modal--transition">
    <a class="modal__close" href="#">X</a>
    <img src="{{cells.ImageURL}}">
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript (jQuery)

```
$(document).on('click', "a.btn", function() {
  $('.modal').toggleClass('modal--show');
      });

$(document).on('click', '.overlay', function() {
  $('.modal').toggleClass('modal--show');
});

$(document).on('click', '.modal__close', function() {
  $('.modal').toggleClass('modal--show');
});
```

CSS

```
.overlay {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.modal {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.modal__contents {
  background: white;
  width: 32rem;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -16rem;
  top: 6rem;
  min-height: 32rem;
}

.modal__contents h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 32rem;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}

.modal__close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 2rem;
  top: 2rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: none;
}

.modal--show {
  visibility: visible;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute !important;
    z-index: 50;
    opacity: 1;
    height: 100%;
}

.modal--transition {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.7);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.7);
    -ms-transform: scale(0.7);
    transform: scale(0.7);
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

.modal--show .modal--transition {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
}
```

I think what is throwing this off is since the button to activate this is generated by the `handlebar.js` template, it is copied and made dynamically and can't seem to single out the one that is being clicked?

Is there a way I can get this to work so it pulls the `{{cells.ImageURL}}` of the same `cell` where it was clicked on?

Here is a **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uqbh4y3m/72/embedded/result/)** to show you what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).on('click', "a.btn", function() {
     $('.modal img').prop('src', $(this).data('img'));
     $('.modal').toggleClass('modal--show');
});
```

although that means that every button would need a `data-img=""` attribute with the corresponding image or if the image is within the a element you could use

```
$(document).on('click', "a.btn", function() {
     $('.modal img').prop('src', $(this).find('img').prop('src'));
     $('.modal').toggleClass('modal--show');
});
```

Comment: since every button needs the `data-img=""`, could I *theoretically* use `{{cells.ImageURL}}`? That way it pulls the image from the query?

Comment: I added the top part and it's throwing a `Uncaught TypeError: this.data is not a function` error. If I add the bottom section, it throws an `img not defined error`

Comment: It seems like it's back to square 1, now it's opening all of the images at once.. hmmm [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/uqbh4y3m/82/embedded/result/)

Comment: I just did it with your JS fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/uqbh4y3m/85/ you took my answer like it was going to work like copy paste it in, coding requires thinking, so why not doing it when you implements some1's solution, i'm not going to do all the work for you ... but now that I have I can rant </rant>

Comment: Sorry man, I'm just not very good at JS. I still can't really wrap my head around your solution, I'll have to look more into it. It works now so thanks for the help, appreciate it a ton!

Comment: can you accept the answer then so other people that can wrap there heads around it might find it usefull